# wpf - how to can write below DataGridCheckBoxColumn in c# code behind?

Tags: wpf, checkbox

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            IsThreeState="True"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterCellStyle}"
            CanUserReorder="False" 
            CanUserResize="False" Header="IsChecked">
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllServerConnectionChkBx">
            <CheckBox 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.HeaderChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                x:Name="ckbSelectedAllServerConnections" 
                Checked="UpCheckbox_Checked" 
                Margin="10,0,5,0"       
                Unchecked="UpCheckbox_Checked" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>

<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}" >
        <EventSetter Event="Checked" Handler="OnChecked" />
        <EventSetter Event="Unchecked" Handler="OnUnChecked"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Comment: Hello hms, please understand that Stackoverflow is not your code-writing service. If you have issues translating a specific part, you should ask about this part only and include what you already figured out yourself. The presented XAML is certainly not suitable as a question of how to transform into code (as a principle). It contains to many trivial property setters and to many different aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to create the `ElementStyle`:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(CheckBox));
style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnChecked)));
style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(CheckBox.UncheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnUnChecked)));
```

If you want to be able to create the `HeaderTemplate` dynamically you could use the `XamlReader.Parse` method (without event handlers):

```
string xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" x:Name=\"dtAllServerConnectionChkBx\"><CheckBox VerticalAlignment=\"Center\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\" IsChecked=\"{Binding Path=DataContext.HeaderChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}\" x:Name=\"ckbSelectedAllServerConnections\" Margin=\"10,0,5,0\"/></DataTemplate>";
DataTemplate dt = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as DataTemplate;

DataGridCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
column.HeaderTemplate = dt;
column.CellStyle = style;
```

To be able to hook up the event handlers you need to do some hack, like for example creating a custom `CheckBox` control as suggested here:

[Attaching an Event Handler to a Code Generated DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650294/attaching-an-event-handler-to-a-code-generated-datatemplate)

Or you could just define the `DataTemplate` in your `<Windows.Resources>` element in your XAML markup and reference it like this:

```
column.HeaderTemplate = Resources["dtAllServerConnectionChkBx"] as DataTemplate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I used your code but unfortunately my issues still is remained. I've attached my code further to see why I am not getting selected rows after checked & unchecked in my dynamic datagrid.

Comment: Attached your code? Where? Also, I fail to see how this related to your original question about how to create the objects programmatically. Please ask a new question if you have a new issue.

Comment: @mm8 he had "attached" his code as an answer and it was then removed by someone.