# Creating a HierarchicalDataTemplate in Silverlight with code

Tags: silverlight, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate, xamlreader

I'm trying to create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (from the Silverlight Toolkit) in code in Silverlight following this advice on creating `DataTemplates` from code:

[Creating a Silverlight DataTemplate in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code)

However, I haven't been able to get it to work for `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

I tried using `XamlBuilder` that ships with Silverlight Toolkit, but that gives me an error.

I've tried `XamlReader`, and have included various default and prefixed namespaces, but with no luck.

If I run `XamlBuilder`'s Build method, I get the following string:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" xmlns:attached=\"clr-namespace:MyStuff;assembly=MyStuff\" xmlns=\"clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows.Controls\"><attached:MyUserControl /></HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The error I get is:

> AG_E_PARSER_NAMESPACE_NOT_SUPPORTED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Silverlight Xaml parser, the default xmlns *must* be "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", even if you don't use it. So add that xmlns declaration to your Xaml string, and change the System.Windows clr-namespace declaration to use some prefix.

Comment: Thanks, Keith.  Hopefully the Silverlight Toolkit folks will update XamlBuilder so it does this correctly.