# How to create DataTemplate at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, datatemplate

I have defined the DataTemplate in the XAML, however I need to change it to be defined at run time, because its binding is dynamic.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="myCellTemplate">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="4"/>
   </DataTemplate>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Is there any way to define it in code-behind?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Silverlight DataTemplate in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to accomplish what you need with a custom [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) and I'd recommend that approach, if possible.  That said, it is possible to create a DataTemplate in code:

```
Type type = typeof(MyUserControl); //for example    
var template = new DataTemplate();
template.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(type);
return template;
```

In this context, `type` is the type of visual element you want to have as the root of your template.  If necessary, you could add additional elements using the factory, but in the one case where I've used this, I simply created UserControl elements to represent the different templates I was dynamically creating.

---

My apologies, this apparently isn't supported in Silverlight.  In Silverlight, you have to use [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189076%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you . I'm working with Silverlight 3 and I couldn't find FrameworkElementFactory

Comment: Thank you . In regards to your answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code