# WPF DataTemplate with Binding

Tags: wpf, combobox

A WPF ComboBox/ListBox itemtemplate/datatemplate question please.

Let's say that I set DisplayMember="Name", this is equivalent to

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

"Name" is a field in my view model.

Now, if DisplayMember="{Binding Name}", "Name" is no longer a property in my view model but instead contains the name of the property in my view model that I want to display.  Using an ItemTemplate, how would I set this up? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2769947/1136211

Answer (score 0):

DisplayMemberPath is a property of the ItemsControl. And its binding path will be resolved relative to the ItemsControl's DataContext, not its items.

Example (pseudo code without INPC interface implementation):

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    // This sets the string name of the property (or the path to it)
    // to be displayed in the items.
    public string DisplayNameProperty {get; set;} = "Name" // Or = "Surname"

    // Items Source
    public IEnumerable Items {get; set;}
}
```

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayNameProperty}"/>
```

The binding in the DisplayMemberPath property will allow you to control from the ViewModel which property will be displayed in ItemsControl's items.

But in practice, such a task is extremely rare.
Personally, in my practice, such a need has never arisen.

Comment: In a large financial application, I have probably 100 lists that need to be displayed in a combobox and I do not want to develop 100 different item templates. (Clemens response is for template selector.) I have a base class that manages all of this, and using DisplayMember="{Binding Name}" handled this nicely. I need to style the dropdown portion of a combobox, so I need to implement an item template with the same functionality that binding DisplayMember provided me.