# Creating Data template for ListBox for WindowPhone7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to create data-template for the list box in WP7 using C# code instead of XAML??

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate a `DataTemplate` in code in the same way that you can for regular controls, but you can use the `XamlReader.Load()` method to create a `DataTemplate` from a XAML string:

```
string xaml = @"<DataTemplate
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
  <!-- Template content goes here. -->
</DataTemplate>";
var dt = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

Be sure to add any additional namespaces that you might need.
The answer to this question also shows that you can create bindings in the `DataTemplate` in the same way: [Creating a Silverlight DataTemplate in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code).

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try using the same