# Displaying a ComboBox of AudioCaptureDevices

Tags: c#, silverlight, collections, combobox

I want to create a `ComboBox` control in code (no XAML) which displays the list of available `AudioCaptureDevice`s.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<AudioCaptureDevice> audioDevices;
audioDevices = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetAvailableAudioCaptureDevices();

StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
ComboBox cbxAudioDevices = new ComboBox();
cbxAudioDevices.ItemsSource = audioDevices;
sp.Children.Add(cbxAudioDevices);
this.RootVisual = sp;
```

However, instead of displaying nice-looking names, only entries named *System.Windows.Media.AudioCaptureDevice* are shown.
The nice-looking names would be available through the `FriendlyName` property of the `AudioCaptureDevice`.

Is there an easy way to convert my collection so that it will display the friendly names, but will still hold the `AudioCaptureDevice`s? Or will I have to create a second collection with only the names, and then take my original collection to get the other properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a DataTemplate to help present the AudioCaptureDevice objects. You can do this in code as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code). You would use that DataTemplate and assign it to your ComboBox's ItemTemplate property.

Comment: That did the trick. `<DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FriendlyName}"/></DataTemplate>`