# Problems with XamlReader generating DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, datatemplate, xamlreader

I'm trying to implement the code below in my WPF project in order to generate DataTemplates on the fly for a DataGrid with dynamic columns. I found the code on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code)

```
public DataTemplate Create(Type type)
{
  return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
          @"<DataTemplate
            xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"">
            <" + type.Name + @" Text=""{Binding " + ShowColumn + @"}""/>
            </DataTemplate>"
   );
}
```

However, on the XamlReader.Load code, I get the error "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Xaml.XamlReader'.

I tried to get around this by changing the code to:

```
return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(XmlReader.Create(
```

but I get errors about passing invalid characters in the string.

Also, I am unsure how to pass a TextBlock to this code. I imagined I would just create a TextBlock and pass it as the Type argument, but I get the error "cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' to 'System.Type'

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How many distinct controls in that default namespace have a "Text" property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```cs
public DataTemplate Create(Type type)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
    @"<DataTemplate 
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""> 
            <" + type.Name + @" Text=""{Binding " + ShowColumn + @"}""/> 
        </DataTemplate>");
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
}
```

Call it like this

```cs
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
Create(textBlock.GetType());
```

Comment: +1 for GetType but I don't think the XmlReader, StringReader is really necessary.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: You are right, just using `XmlReader.Create` in `XamlReader.Load` will do.

Comment: I'm not convinced the XmlReader is needed either.  I do this sort of thing a lot and I just use a String.  If there was a genuine error regarding invalid characters the use of XmlReader in that manner is not going to fix it.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I'm not sure how it works in Silverlight but in WPF, `XamlReader.Load` doesn't accept a string as parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx. Do you have an alternate way?

Comment: Good point, In Silverlight Load _only_ takes a string.  This is always a problem when questioners include both tags, we need to read the "fine print" to discern what they are actually working in.  In this case Caustix is asking a WPF question. D'oh!

Comment: I may be ignorent, but what is the purpose of @ in the strings passed for the StringReader

Comment: Adarsha - it allows you to have a string on multiple lines without the needs for explicit concatenation (+)

Comment: Problem with this is the template cannot use x:Bind.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code with the workaround for XmlReader and it worked fine without any issues. Please try this:

```
 return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
                XmlReader.Create(
                    @"<DataTemplate  xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007""><" + type.Name + @" Text=""{Binding " + ShowColumn + @"}""/>
            </DataTemplate>"
             ));
```

This should work.