# How to define a Data Template in c#?

Tags: silverlight

How can I create a DataTemplate in code (using C#) and then add a control to that DataTemplate?

```
<data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border>
            <Border Margin="10" Padding="10" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" 
                 BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     FontSize="10">
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

I am using Sivlerlight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to create a `DataTemplate` in `Silverlight` is to use `XamlReader`. Basically you would just pass it the XAML as a string and it will give you back a DataTemplate. Byron's solution would apply to WPF but Silverlight (to the best of my knowledge) does not support FrameworkElementFactory.

[Defining Silverlight DataGrid Columns at Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/04/14/defining-silverlight-datagrid-columns-at-runtime.aspx)

Take note of option #2 for `DataGridTemplateColumn`.